# Azure Logic App Store Excel Email Attachment To Blob, Download and Read

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, openxml

I have setup an azure logic app that listens for an email with a particular title. That email has an excel attachment. When the email arrives it pushes the attachment to an Azure blob and puts a message on a queue.

I then have a function app that listens for that message and attempts to process the file.

I have the following code which downloads the blob as a stream:

```
BlobContainerClient containerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
BlobDownloadInfo download = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
using Stream downloadFileStream = new MemoryStream();
await download.Content.CopyToAsync(downloadFileStream);
downloadFileStream.Position = 0;
```

I then convert that to an Azure blob object that looks like this:

```
public class AzureBlob
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContentBytes { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public bool IsInline { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
    public string ContentId { get; set; }
}
```

using this code:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(downloadFileStream);
string fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
AzureBlob blob = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AzureBlob>(fileContents);
```

I then try and open it with OpenXML like this:

(The "ContentType" comes back as "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")

```
Stream stockFileStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(blob.ContentBytes));
SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stockFileStream, true);
```

But i get the error of:

> **System.IO.FileFormatException: File contains corrupted data.**

Can anyone help me find what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: Have you tried to open this file into any application handling this format so you can at least figure if it's really corrupt?

Comment: when i do this, excel fails to open it as well await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(@"C:\Users\Trevo\Desktop\KockStock.xlsx", Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(blob.ContentBytes));

Comment: Could you please confirm that the excel file stored in the storage by the `azure logic app` is intact?

Comment: @FrankGong how would i do that please?

Comment: So if it doesn't open in Excel and it's from an email, consider it harmful as it could be literally anything else than what it pretends to be. You can always check the content with Notepad.

Comment: You can try to [download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orJl8.png) the excel file directly to the local and check if it is intact.

Comment: the azure blob is a json file with the file bytes in it.. so it doesn't come down as a xlxs file :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by altering the class slightly:

```
public class AzureBlob
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] ContentBytes { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public bool IsInline { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
    public string ContentId { get; set; }
}
```

and a slight alteration to my code converting it to a stream:

```
// get the file
BlobContainerClient containerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
BlobDownloadInfo download = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
        
// convert the stream to an azure blob object
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(download.Content);
string fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
AzureBlob blob = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AzureBlob>(fileContents);

// convert the stock file to a stream
Stream stockFileStream = new MemoryStream(blob.ContentBytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

I find `blob.ContentBytes` is a base64 String, you need to use [Convert.FromBase64String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=net-5.0) to convert it to bytes[].

```
Stream stockFileStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(blob.ContentBytes));
```